# "Freeze out" degrees of freedom (Specific heat)

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

I am reading about Einstein's specific heat model for solids where author says that:

> However, at low temperature the degrees of freedom “freeze out”, the system gets stuck in only the ground state eigenstate, and the heat capacity vanishes rapidly.

I suppose that at lower temperatures atoms don't have enough energy for example to rotate, but can't explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thermal energy for each degree of freedom is given by
$$\frac{1}{2} k_{B} T $$
If this thermal energy is lower than the gap between ground state and first excited state (supposing quantised energy levels) then a thermal excitation becomes very unlikely. I would guess that this is what the author means by "frozen" degrees of freedom.

For a more precise answer it would help if you would give the reference of your quote.

Comment: http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/SteveSimon/condmat2012/LectureNotes2012.pdf p.24

Really hope to see some model that tells you what energy is needed to "activate" other degrees of freedom.

Comment: if you want a calculation to show you "for system x, degree of freedom y, the energy level quantisation is the following" I cannot provide that because it is a very complicated question I think. For toy models you might find examples in good standard texts on solid state physics, but this would be a bit unfitting to the PSE format and I honestly don't know any by heart either. You might want to edit your question or post a new one though and if you want, I'll remove this answer because I probably misunderstood the question.